# Does the File Uploading Custom Components works for FSL mobile app?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, servicecloud, field-service-lightning, salesforce-mobile-app

I have created a Lightning Web Component (LWC) that successfully converts multiple images into a single PDF in my developer org. However, when I try to use the same LWC component in my Field Service Lightning (FSL) mobile app, it does not function as expected. Additionally, I attempted to add the component to the Lightning home page, but it does not appear on the page as expected.

I tried to add my LWC component in FSL mobile app but it does not appear on the page.My Expecting was to add the LWC component in FSL mobile app

Comment: Could you present the key sections of your LWC (html, js, but in particular your ...js-meta.xml)? I think this would facilitate answering your question.